# safari transform rotateX animation bug

Tags: html, css, safari

When I run this animation on Safari, there is a unwanted offset between wrapper and target, which should be at the center of wrapper. This code work well on others browsers including IE.

A strange thing is that the position of the target in developer tool is correct, but it just rendered with offset.
[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w8HS.png)

Is there any hack to take over this problem?

My safari version: 10.1.1

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%);
}
.target{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-animation: flip 2s;
          animation: flip 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip{
 0%{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(0deg);
          transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(0deg);
 }
 100%{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(360deg);
          transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes flip{
 0%{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(0deg);
          transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(0deg);
 }
 100%{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(360deg);
          transform: translate(-50%,0) rotateX(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Still seeing this in Safari 12.1.1. Did you ever find out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .target{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-animation: flip 2s;
            animation: flip 2s;
  }



@keyframes flip{
 0%{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(60px,0) rotateX(0deg);
          transform: translate(60px,0) rotateX(0deg);
 }
 100%{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0) rotateX(360deg);
          transform: translate(0px,0) rotateX(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

u can try this code..

Comment: But this code makes the target not at the center of the wrapper :( And why "left: -30px;" ?  Thanks for answering!